# Use a set of javascript variables in an email

Tags: javascript, outlook

I need to get something working but i am really out of my depth here.
This is the situation:

- I have a webpage that is filled with checkboxes
- On selection of certain checkboxes a certain piece of text is needed in an email
- The email has some standard things in it including a logo in the top and some images at the bottom
- When a generate button is pressed outlook will open with the composed email

The webpage part isn't the problem, but how will I get outlook to open and fill in the body tag with the items mentioned as above?